# Манипуляция пикселями изображения напрямую

Tags: python

Был вдохновлён данным видео https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gLzuTcyjRVI про конформные отображения.
Я пробовал реализовать подобное через python. В качестве конформного отображения для начала выбирал функцию линейную.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt


# def func_zhukovsky(z):
#     return (z + 1 / z) / 2


def func_linear(z, k, b):
    return z * k + b

img = plt.imread('./img.jpg')
res = img.copy()


for y in range(1620):
    for x in range(2160):
        z = complex(x, y)

        Z = func_linear(z, 1, -300)

        if 0 < Z.real < 1620 and 0 < Z.imag < 2160:
            res[int(Z.real), int(Z.imag)] = res[x, y]
        else:
            res[x, y] = 0


plt.imshow(res)
plt.show()
```

Хоть и получил линейный сдвиг на 300px (как и ожидалось), есть чувство как будто всё делаю не так.

1. Во-первых, проход по изображению выходит слегка долгим (возможно, так и должно быть. я не знаю). Может мне стоило использовать модуль Pillow
2. Во-вторых, меня сейчас больше волнует, как на видео удалось добиться плавного отображения одной области в другую. Это просто использовали кучу фото подряд?
3. В-третьих, вот эта строчка `res[int(Z.real), int(Z.imag)] = res[x, y]`, наверняка, сильно огрубляет результат (если бы использовал в качестве отображения не линейную функцию, а функцию Жуковского, то вряд ли бы получил то, что хотел). Слышал, что в JavaScript пиксели могут принимать дробные значения. Может стоило вообще на JS писать?

Поэтому мой главный вопрос такой: какое средство мне выбрать, чтобы реализовать что-то подобное, как на видео?
Спасибо

Вот кстати результат программы, кому интересно:

[image: Результат программы]

Comment: Вы импортируете numpy, но совсем не используете его и компилируете себе жизнь.

Comment: @MarianD, точно) он будет использоваться на другом этапе

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если поместить ваши циклы внутрь функции и обернуть потом эту функцию и func_linear в декоратор `jit` из пакета `numba`, то всё будет летать без дополнительных усилий. При первом вызове функция немного притормозит, поскольку ей надо будет скомпилироваться (но всё равно выполнится быстрее), а последующие вызовы будут по меньшей мере в 10 раз быстрее работать, а то и в 100.
Картинки вашей у меня нет, поэтому использую произвольный numpy массив.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pylab as plt
from numba import jit

# def func_zhukovsky(z):
#     return (z + 1 / z) / 2

@jit
def func_linear(z, k, b):
    return z * k + b

img = np.ones((2160,1620))
res = img.copy()

@jit
def doit(res):
    for y in range(1620):
        for x in range(2160):
            z = complex(x, y)

            Z = func_linear(z, 1, -300)

            if 0 < Z.real < 1620 and 0 < Z.imag < 2160:
                res[int(Z.real), int(Z.imag)] = res[x, y]
            else:
                res[x, y] = 0
```

Без декоратора: 3 секунды

С декоратором: 300 мс, при повторных вызовах функции возможно ещё быстрее будет - в первый вызов numba ещё и успевает скомпилировать функции.